# ¿Por qué los detalles de una compra no se almacenan en mi tabla 'compra' en Laravel usando la API de PayPal?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel-8

hola buen dia alguien me podria ayudar con un error que estoy teniendo les comento estoy haciendo una tienda virtual con el framework Laravel ya se agrega al carrito de compra y con la cual estoy usando una api de paypal para que se pueda simular una compra real pero el problema esta en que yo cree una base de datos con varias tablas pero una en especifica que se llama "compra" con la cual se creo con migrate  en esa tabla se tiene almacena los datos de las compras pero no entiendo el porque no se esta almacenando los detalles de dicha compra.

este archivo se llama pago.blade.php

```
{{--  --}}

<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        style:{
            color: 'blue',
            shape: 'pill',
            label: 'pay'
        },

        createOrder: function(data,actions){
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units:[{
                    amount:{
                        value: '{{ $total }}'
                    }
                }]
            });
        },

        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    let url = '{{ route('carrito.captura') }}';

    actions.order.capture().then(function(detalles) {
        console.log(detalles);

        let url = '{{ route('carrito.captura') }}';

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('_token', '{{ csrf_token() }}');
        formData.append('detalles', JSON.stringify(detalles));

        return fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        });
    });
},



        onCancel: function(data){
            alert("pago cancelado")
        }

    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

el siguiente archivo es mi archivo CarritoController

```
public function captura(Request $request){
$json = $request->getContent();
$datos = json_decode($json, true);

if (is_array($datos)) {
    $id_transaccion = $datos['detalles']['id'];
    $total = $datos['detalles']['purchase_units'][0]['amount']['value'];
    $status = $datos['detalles']['status'];
    $fecha = $datos['detalles']['update_time'];
    $fecha_nueva = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($fecha));
    $email = $datos['detalles']['payer']['email_address'];
    $id_cliente = $datos['detalles']['payer']['payer_id'];

    $compra = new Compra();
    $compra->id_transaccion = $id_transaccion;
    $compra->fecha = $fecha_nueva;
    $compra->status = $status;
    $compra->email = $email;
    $compra->id_cliente = $id_cliente;
    $compra->total = $total;
    $compra->save();

    $id = $compra->id;

   
}
```

y esta es mis rutas

```
Route::post('/captura', [CarritoController::class, 'captura'])->name('carrito.captura');
```

este es mi archivo compra.php con la esta el nombre de las columnas de mi tabla compra.

```
class Compra extends Model{
use HasFactory;
protected $table = 'compra';
protected $fillable = [
    'id_transaccion',
    'fecha',
    'status',
    'email',
    'id_cliente',
    'total'
];}
```

[image: esta es la tabla compra en mi base de datos]